# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'. Flutter

Tags: php, android, mysql, flutter

I'm having a trouble, why I'm getting this error in my app flutter `main.dart`
I just follow this reference [link](https://github.com/idrcorner/Flutter-Login-MySQL/blob/master/lib/main.dart).  It would be great if anybody could figure out, thank you so much in advance!.

*Here's the error part*

```
Future<List> _login() async {
   final response = await http.post("http://10.0.2.2/my_store/login.php", body: {
      "username": user.text,
      "password": pass.text,
 });
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `parse` your URLs now, use it like this:

```
Future<List> _login() async {
   final response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2/my_store/login.php"), body: {
      "username": user.text,
      "password": pass.text,
 });
```